# Java, access secure WSO2 web service with Username and Password

Tags: java, web-services, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a Maven project and am successfully connected to an insecure web service that has been created with WSO2. When the security is enabled, how do I pass the credentials, namely the Username and Password, to connect to the service?

Firstly, can I do it quickly by introducing the Username and Password in the Java code itself?

Do I have to generate a certificate like I've seen in a few of the articles or is there any other way to get this done?

My `pom.xml` has the following entry

```
<execution>
    <id>getTestService</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
        <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
        <packageName>com.test.esb</packageName>
        <wsdlFile>http://test:8080/services/getTestService?wsdl</wsdlFile>
        <syncMode>sync</syncMode>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

and in my Java class, I am calling the service with the below code.

```
final TestServiceStub testStub = new TestServiceStub();
final TestServiceDocument testDoc = 
    TestServiceDocument.Factory.newInstance();

final TestService testReq = TestService.Factory.newInstance();

...

testDoc.setTestService(testReq);
testStub.TestService(testDoc);
```

Comment: Are you referring to a hosted service in WSO2 Application Server? and what kind of security is enabled? is it Username Token?

Comment: @Nadeesha: Appreciate the very quick response, but I'm not sure as the web service is being exposed by another team. Will update as soon as I get the information from them.

Comment: @Nadeesha, yes, security is enabled with a Username Token. Any idea on how I might go about implementing the authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this covers your scenario, but [this](http://code.chamiladealwis.com/blog/2014/07/19/consuming-a-service-secured-by-wso2-esb/) blog post elaborates on how to access a Username-token secured service in Java. You need to have the certificate of the server in your trust store and you need to provide the username and the password to the stub.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. The link did help out a lot. Had to generate the certificate and follow the procedure in the given link. Thanks for the help.